# Insert sql file into sqlite - iphone

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am new to SQLite

I have a `.sql` script file, `details.sql`, given here:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into Student(student_id, name, address) Values ('101', '123', 'Marthandam');
Insert into Student(student_id, name, address) Values ('102', 'Abc', 'Chennai');
Insert into Student(student_id, name, address) Values ('103', 'Xyz', 'TVM');
COMMIT;
```

I need to insert these queries from `details.sql` into the sqlite3 data base on an iPhone.  On the iPhone I have created a new DB for storage called Database.sql

Please give me the source code to insert the scripts into Database.sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something like this:

```
NSString *f = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:<path to details.sql> encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
for (NSString *l in [f componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
   <call sqlite3_exec to execute each line of SQL>
}
```